# Batch file to delete selected files

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

In most modern systems, the system will automatically create extra files that are unnecessary. How can I create a .bat file that makes use of a checklist to delete any file that isn't on it?

This would be useful for removing automatically generated backup files, plot logs, error logs, etc. in the customization files I have created.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'checklist'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file called 'deletestuff.bat' (or whatever you want it to be called, as long as it is a `.bat`). Next, fill it with:

```
rm *.tmp
rm *.blah
```

Where `.tmp`, and `.blah` are the extensions of the files that you would like to delete (they might be `.log`, for instance). Test it first by copying a sample of files into a new folder and running the new `.bat` there, just to make sure it doesn't delete important things.

Comment: Yeah that is an option though i wanted more the rverse keep things on the list remove all that isnt, that would keep it more tidy

Comment: hmm… relying on file extensions is not good with batch scripts, because if 8.3 filenames are still active, `del *.txt` might also remove all `.txtwhatever` files. Try `del *.doc`, it will also delete all docx, docm, docz files.

Comment: Side note: `rm` will not work out of the box. Use `del` or `erase`. On that note, though, Benoits complaints are irrelevant, since `rm` is not a shell built-in and therefore is not subject to the same restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, make sure to set SEARCHDIR to the real dir, and populate keep.txt with the files you want to keep, 1 file per line, use the full path including the dir. If you don't want to use the dir, adjust the `DIR /S /B` command so it outputs the same format as what is in your keep.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set KEEPFILES=keep.txt
set SEARCHDIR=.\test_folder
SET /a KEEPTHISFILE=2

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ( 'DIR /S /B %SEARCHDIR%\*' ) DO (
SET /a KEEPTHISFILE=0
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%B in ( '"type %KEEPFILES%"') do (
    if "%%A"=="%%B" SET /a KEEPTHISFILE=1       
)
if "!KEEPTHISFILE!"=="0" (
    echo "deleting %%A"
    del /f %%A  
)
)
```

Comment: A question: would this work with wildcards in the keep file? As in, *.txt and the like.

Comment: Nope, this only does exact file matching